# misalignment of column values in a tabular* / dcolumn table

Tags: tabularx, columns, dcolumn

I am using the following code to create a table for a paper I am writing in Overleaf.

```
\usepackage{array}       
\usepackage{dcolumn}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{l@{\extracolsep{\fill}}d{5.5}d{5.8}d{5.5}}
\toprule
\noalign{\vskip 0.2in}
&  \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fisher-Zou} &
 \multicolumn{1}{c}{Wilcox-Muska} \\
    \multicolumn{1}{c}{GROUP} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{p-value} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CI's} & \multicolumn{1}{c}{CI's} \\
 \noalign{\vskip 0.2in}
 \midrule 
 \noalign{\vskip 0.2in} 
\multicolumn{1}{c}{females} \\
\noalign{\vskip 0.1in}
(A vs. B) & .0043 & .0083-.5788 & -.0671-.4987 \\
(A vs. C) & .0005 & .1630-.5764 & .0767-.4990 \\
(A vs. D) & .0096 & .0789-.6195 & .0062-.5262 \\
(A vs. E) & .6926 & -.2448-.1991 & -.1997-.1475 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}     
\end{table}
```

The problem is that the values do not centre under the subheadings p-value, CI's and CI's, which in turn do not position correctly under the headings Fisher-Zou (should encompass data columns 2 and 3)and Wilcox-Muska (the final data column).

Any suggestions please?

Comment: A quick hint: If you highlight the lines of LaTeX code and click on the `{}` "button" in the row above the editing window, they'll be shifted four spaces to the right and will be pretty-printed by the site software.

Comment: @Mico sorry, I was just in the process of editing to display the code properly when you posted your edit!

Comment: What means number `.0083-.5788`? Is the second part a tolerance of the first part of number?

Comment: @Zarko it represents a confidence interval so 'between' .0083 and .5788

Comment: Isn't than better to type them in stabdard columns? Like `...& .0083 & -.5788 & ...` ?

Comment: if it would format better then yes I could do that. In principle, the two numbers belong together as it represents an interval, so I didn't immediately think of separating them into two columns.

Comment: Zarko, given Mico's answer then, yes separating the numbers was indeed the correct approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

an alternative ... with`tabularx` and `siunitx` instead of `D` columns:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}

\usepackage{siunitx}

    \begin{document}
\begin{table}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X S[table-format=1.4]
                 *{2}{S[table-format=-2.4]@{\quad--\quad}S[table-format=0.4]@{\qquad}}
                  }
    \toprule
&  \multicolumn{3}{c}{Fisher-Zou} 
    &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{Wilcox-Muska}                \\
    \cmidrule(r){2-4}\cmidrule(l){5-6}
\multicolumn{1}{c}{GROUP} 
    &   {p-value} 
        &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{CI's} 
            &   \multicolumn{2}{c}{CI's}                \\
    \midrule
females   &   \multicolumn{5}{c}{}                      \\
    \addlinespace
(A vs. B) & .0043 &  .0083 & .5788  & -.0671 & .4987    \\
(A vs. C) & .0005 &  .1630 & .5764  &  .0767 & .4990    \\
(A vs. D) & .0096 &  .0789 & .6195  &  .0062 & .5262    \\
(A vs. E) & .6926 & -.2448 & .1991  & -.1997 & .1475    \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: I'm not sure whether "Fisher-Zou" should span columns 2, 3,and 4 or just columns 3 and 4. Let's see if the OP weighs in with more Information.

Comment: yep,  with the added advantage that the p-value sits under the Fisher-Zou heading (the R package for Wilcox-Muska only computes intervals).

Comment: yes, sorry Mico I should have picked that up immediately, the Fisher-Zou is p-values and the first CI's. It will be good practice to use your code and see if I can get it looking like Zarko's solution. Looks like I can only mark one answer as acceptable or best?  But I think both would work. Mico's Version could be described adequately in the caption.

Answer (score 2):

When using the `D` column type, be careful to provide only one number containing a decimal marker per cell. Also, take care to distinguish between a typographic `-` ("minus") and `--` ("en-dash") symbol.

I would suggest you organize the table as follows:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage{dcolumn,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{d}[1]{D{.}{.}{#1}}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{} l d{1.4} *{2}{d{2.4}@{\,--\,}d{1.4}} @{}}
\toprule
\addlinespace
Group & \multicolumn{1}{c}{$p$-value}
 & \multicolumn{2}{c}{Fisher-Zou} 
 & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{Wilcox-Muska} \\
 && \multicolumn{2}{c}{CIs} & \multicolumn{2}{c@{}}{CIs} \\
\addlinespace
\midrule  
\addlinespace
Females \\
\addlinespace
(A vs.\ B) & 0.0043 &  0.0083 & 0.5788 & -0.0671& 0.4987 \\
(A vs.\ C) & 0.0005 &  0.1630 & 0.5764 &  0.0767& 0.4990 \\
(A vs.\ D) & 0.0096 &  0.0789 & 0.6195 &  0.0062& 0.5262 \\
(A vs.\ E) & 0.6926 & -0.2448 & 0.1991 & -0.1997& 0.1475 \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}     
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you, that was exactly what I wanted. I'll work through your solution so that I understand how to format my tables correctly in the future.